# Do C90-compliant compilers have to take into account instruction reordering by the CPU?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, assembly, standards

Consider the following piece of code:

```
volatile int a;
volatile int b;
int x;

void func() {
    a = 1;
    x = 0; /* dummy statement */
    b = 2;
}
```

In this code snippet, the assignment to x constitutes a sequence point. Hence, according to the C90 standard, the access to the volatile variable a must be finished before the access to b is started. When translating this piece of code to x86-64 assembler, the body of the function is translated as follows:

```
movl $1, a(%rip)
movl $0, x(%rip)
movl $2, b(%rip)
```

Now, when executing this code, the CPU may reorder the memory accesses, thus breaking the requirement of the C standard that the accesses to a and b are performed in order. So, isn't this translation incorrect, and wouldn't the compiler have to to insert memory barriers to enforce the ordering?

Edit:
Consider the case where a and b are variables shared by two threads. In this case, a synchronization protocol between the two threads may rely on the fact that accesses to a and b occur in order. Thus, when the CPU reorders the accesses, this may break that protocol (I'm not actually trying to implement such a protocol, I'm just wondering what the correct interpretation of the C standard is).

Comment: CPU instruction reordering (assuming we're talking about something like an x86) is designed to be transparent; it should have no effect on the logical outcome of the program.

Comment: As far as I understand it is generally the CPU's job to implicitly add the necessary synchronization required for out of order execution. Generally it will keep memory operations on the same part of memory synchronous with each other, so it behaves as if the accesses were not reordered.

Comment: CPU instruction reordering does not ensure that the outcome of the program is the same. Consider communication among multiple threads through shared variables, or accessing an external device.

Answer (score 6):

CPUs might reorder instructions but they have to make sure **the outcome is the same as if they hadn't**.

Comment: +1: exactly.  (The exception is, of course, if you're relying on the outcome of e.g. a race hazard between threads, which is already undefined behaviour).

Comment: And CPU-reordering constraints are way much stringent than the usual C standard "as-if" rule, since even the state of the real processor must be kept "as if" reordering hadn't happened.

Comment: But volatile data is often used to communicate with external devices, or for data shared among threads. In these cases, when the CPU reorders memory accesses, the outcome may not be the same as if the accesses occured in order. The memory access reordering of CPUs thus does not ensure that the outcome is the same as if it hadn't reordered the accesses.

Comment: Now if a C progammer relies on the guarantees given in the C standard (i.e. certain accesses occuring in order), this could result in an incorrect program.

Comment: @HermannSpeiche: If your only form of thread-safety is to use `volatile`, then you will have problems even without CPU instruction reordering.  You should be using proper thread-synchronization mechanisms.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: I know, I'm just wondering what the correct interpretation of the C standard is in this case.

Comment: @HermannSpeiche If the volatile data communicates with external devices, I think the CPU won't reorder the instructions.

Comment: @Hermann: The C standard says exactly what you say in your question; `volatile` is only a guarantee with respect to sequence points.  The C standard has no concept of threads: in a single-threaded environment, CPU reordering has no effect; in a multi-threaded environment, we're outside the scope of the standard...

Comment: @cnicutar: Do you have any prove of this? And how would the CPU know if it communicates with an external device?

Comment: @HermannSpeiche I don't have any and indeed that is a *good* question.  It just seemed the sensible thing.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: *"The C standard has no concept of threads"* -- it does now.  The recently approved ISO C11 standard includes (optional) support for threads.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, but thats C++. Strictly speaking, it is not possible to program thread safe in pure C90. It works of course, with the help of some assembly and a lot of architecture specific code the pthread library, but the C90 language in itself is not sufficient.

Comment: @drhirsch: No, that's C.  Both C and C++ have new ISO standards this year.  http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/, http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=57853

Comment: This answer is true and only true within the context of a single thread.  Reordering certainly can and does affect outcomes when it comes to multi-threading.